# Why A2billing doesn't charge customer-to-customer calls?

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, cdr

I have installed A2Billing+Asterisk13.18-cert3. Outgoing calls are configured and billed correctly.

Once a customer calls another, two CDR records stored, Calltype:DID_Voip and CallType:DID-ALEG, but none of them are charged and the charges are zero.

I googled to find out any workaround to fix the issue. All results were incomplete and outdated.

I created a LOCAL provider, then a TRUNK with Tech=local, Provider IP:a2billing. DIDa are also configured and I can receive calls.

When using simulator, it can find the correct Call Plan and rates. but it doesn't apply to the call.

I have two questions:

(1) How can I setup asterisk to pass the call through a local trunk so A2Billing can apply charges to calls?

(2) What should I do to make A2Billing charge the customer-to-customer calls?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A2Billing designed to charge prefix.

So if you want it charge customer call, you have create prefix and charge it.

You need call go via Local provider, not just create it.